# QDialog with ok and cancel buttons

Tags: c++, qt, button, qdialog, qbuttongroup

I need Qt Dialog with ok and cancel buttons with standard functionality, placed on the right side of its layout. I need to inherit from it and add other widgets to its layout. I can implement it myself, but maybe there is something standard, in that case I prefer to use it, since it will be more portable.

QMessageBox shows a message, I need something more general, only QDialog and standard buttons, or maybe QDialog has an option which activates them.

Comment: QMessageBox is a QDialog with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons already in it. I've never tried to subclass it, though. It may point you in the right direction.

Comment: QMessageBox shows a message, I need something more general, only QDialog and standart buttons, or maybe QDialog has an option which activates them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Subclass `QDialog` and use a `QDialogButtonBox` for the standard buttons ([docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html)).

Answer (score 1):

In case you use QT Designer, learnpyqt.com [has this nice tutorial](https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/creating-dialogs-qt-designer/) in which they describe how to build a QDialog with multiple input fields.
QT Designer can be downloaded as described [here on stackoverflow in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43229814).