# How to install QtDesigner?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I just installed Qt 5.4.1 on Windows 7. And there is no QtDesigner. Also there is no QtDesigner in MaintenanceTool.
How can I install it?

Comment: You can find the designer.exe in the bin folder of your Qt installation (e.g. C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\bin)

Comment: There is no QtDesigner.exe. But thiere is QtDesigner.dll.

Comment: Like I said the file is named designer.exe and not QtDesigner.exe. The QtDesigner.dll belongs to the package as well.

Comment: designer.exe. There is. Thanks.

Comment: https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can install and find QT Designer as follows (Windows environment):

- Install latest QT (I'm using 5.8) from [QT main site](https://www.qt.io/)
- Make sure you include "Qt 5.8 MinGW" component
- QT Designer will be installed in `C:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\bin\designer.exe`
- Note that the executable is named "designer.exe"

**UPDATE** - there is an easier way to install QT Designer without downloading GB's of data from QT:

- Install the latest version of "**pyqt5-tools**" using `pip install pyqt5-tools --pre`
- The "designer.exe" will be installed in `...Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools`

Comment: someone give this guy a cookie THANK YOU !

Comment: For an even smaller download, try my [standalone installer](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download). It's less than 40MB and doesn't even require Python.

Comment: I've always used the pyqt5-tools method, but today I noticed that it downgraded my PyQt from 5.12.2 to 5.11.3 which was beyond my intent. Switched to @MichaelHerrmann's standalone installer for the time being.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins, according to [pyqt5-tools issue #26](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt5-tools/issues/26) it should work providing the --pre flag, but I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: Oh, yes, I didn't mention it but I tried both with and without the --pre flag. They require a new flag nowadays: `pip install --pre pyqt5-tools~=5.12`. This is better than just `--pre` in that it works with 5.12, but still not ideal: it uninstalls the 5.12.2 qt I currently have and installs 5.12.1 instead.

Comment: For anyone doing this the 5.12 version of pyqt5-tools is still in pre-release at the moment (https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/#history) so the "--pre" option is still needed.

Comment: For pyqt6-tools it's in qt6_applications\Qt\bin

Answer (score 8):

If you are on macOS and use brew you may have installed qt already using brews installer.

In that case you already have QT Designer installed even though it is not mentioned anywhere.

You can find it here: `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/<qtversion>/libexec/Designer.app`

So to place it in your local apps folder you can create a symlink to it like this:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.11.1/libexec/Designer.app ~/Applications/.
```

Comment: I was struggling to find the download page, and thanks to your answer just tried, and my Mac found it itself. No clue where it came from, as I didn't use brew (at least not knowingly). Looks like everything was installed automatically by PyCharm.

Answer (score 3):

**Install QtDesigner on windows:**

https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

**install designer on Linux:**

It can be installed using the apt package manager

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 qt4-designer
```

run the command `designer` and it will work for you

if it doesn't try `/usr/bin/designer`

[image]

it worked for me
i am using python 3.6 with pyqt-5.16

Comment: OP is asking about Windows

Answer (score 2):

As of January 2023, the official Qt website does not provide Qt Designer as a standalone Application. Qt Designer can be obtained from:

[**Official source**](https://download.qt.io/)

- Qt Creator + Qt base package

  - Offline installer for Qt Creator *(Qt account required, has integrated Designer)*
- Qt base package

  - Online installer *(Qt account required)*
    Custom Installation, select component
    `Qt-->{Qt Version of choice}-->{Architecture (usually MSVC 64-bit / Mingw64)}`
  - [aqtinstall](https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall) *(NO account needed)*

In all official installations, the standalone `designer.exe` is located in the Qt `bin` folder (for Windows usually `C:\Qt\{Version}\{Architecture}\bin`).

**Third party standalone applications**
*(potentially outdated)*

- https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs
  *(small file size)*
- From PyPi via `pip`
  `pyqt6-tools`, `pyqt5-tools`, `pyqt-tools`, `PyQt5Designer`

For Qt newcomers, using Designer in Creator may be the better choice as it is very straightforward. Advanced users looking to set up a custom build infrastructure may be interested in aqtinstall instead.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* there. Create a form, click on the .ui file and it opens automatically.

Comment: It opens in QtCreator. But I need QtDesigner.

Comment: @Ufx QtDesigner opens inside QtCreator.

Comment: I need QtDesigner application. I know that QtCreator can work with .ui files.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of "pyqt5-tools" using pip install pyqt5-tools --pre

Then run the command (designer.exe) then you are good

Answer (score 1):

> pip install pyqt5-tools

refer: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5Designer/

run the following commands in the given sequence

> pip install PyQt5Designer

> designer.exe

then press Enter. This opens Qt Designer window.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding [StonyBoy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52346716/320369).
If you are on **macOS**, you have installed Qt5 with `brew`, and you want to access the Qt5 Designer app via command line (like on Linux), you can set a symlink to the actual executable as well, like this:

```
ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.13.1/libexec/Designer.app/Contents/MacOS/Designer /usr/local/opt/qt/bin/designer
```

This way, the `designer` command will be placed in the `bin` folder, together with the other Qt5 executables (as `qmake`). Thus, you will be able to launch it simply by typing `designer` in your shell.

---

Note: of course you must have the path of the Qt5 `bin/` folder added to your `PATH` environmental variable, for being able to directly call `designer` in the shell. But `brew` added it for you when you installed Qt5.

Answer (score 0):

I got `pyqt5` installed along with the tools when I `pip install pyqt5-tools`. If you prefer `PySide2`, `qt-tools` will work better. You can emulate a "dry-run" by creating a fresh, disposable virtual environment to test on. Obvious, I know, but I use them infrequently enough that it takes me a while to remember sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, install Qt Design Studio.

After installing it, you should be able to find **designer.exe** by searching for it in the installation directory (using the Windows Explorer find tool for example).

For example in my case, I had installed Qt Design Studio 4.2.0 using the Qt online installer, using **D:\Qt** as installation directory.

**designer.exe** was then under:

```
D:\Qt\Tools\QtDesignStudio\qt6_design_studio_reduced_version\bin\designer.exe
```

Here is a screenshot of what components I selected during the installation:

[image: screenshot of components selected during Qt installation]

Tested on Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install Qt separately, just use "pip install pyqt6" and "pip install pyqt6.tools". After its installed, navigate to the folder where all your modules are downloaded and search for designer in the search bar.  You might need to scroll a little but when you find a green icon with a white D, right click, open file location, right click on the application, create a shortcut so that you don't need to find it all over again. After doing all this, you are good to go.

Answer (score -2):

**I found it here:**

..\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin

Comment: When answering to old questions, provide enough details(like version, platform, etc.,) to support tools asked in question as well as later releases of the tool. Original poster may not be looking for answer now, but whoever searching for similar issue will find it useful if it addresses later version of tools.