# pyqt5_tools designer.exe does not exist

Tags: python, pip

I have installed PyQT5 by command `pip install pyqt5 pyqt5-tools`. Then I want to show path for designer.exe. However I could not found that in **C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools** directory. These are content of that folder.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my system QT Designer is saved under `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Qt Designer`

EDIT:
It seems like I installed QT Designer differently.
You can use `pip install PyQt5Designer`.
Then it should be in the path I gave.

Comment: Here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222572/how-to-install-qtdesigner said that if you install qtdesigner with `pip install pyqt5 pyqt5-tools`. It locates in folder **C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools**.

Comment: Did you check the path that I gave you?

Comment: Yes. I checked that folder there is not QTdesigner.

Comment: Do you maybe have multiple python versions installed? If that is the case its possible the designer is installed for a different python version

Comment: in **C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python** folder I only have one _Python38_ folder I have only one python version installed.

Comment: I modified my answer. Try this solution instead.

Answer (score 10):

using the `pip install pyqt5-tools` method I found the designer on this path:
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin

Comment: did not work for me - there was no python folder in local/programs

Answer (score 2):

`pip install pyqt5-tools`

Check the path `your_python_installed\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin\designer.exe`

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

I Found designer.exe in:

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\Python\[Version]\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it on path
venv\Lib\site-packages\qt5_applications\Qt\bin

Answer (score 1):

If this helps someone, in my case there were two "similar" of pyqt5 folders inside site-packages, ones starts with pyqt5 and others with just qt5, I found the designer app in the folder qt5_aplications.